# Cannot execute ANALYZE during recovery

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-11

We have a insert only table for which we often get bad results due to query plan using nested loops instead of hash joins. To solve this we have to run ANALYZE manually (vacuum sometimes don't run on insret only tables, long story, not the point here). When I try to run analyze on replica machine, I get `ERROR:  cannot execute ANALYZE during recovery` error. So this made me think that we maybe don't need to execute ANALYZE on replica.

My question is: are statistics propagated to replica when executing analyze on master node?

Question in link below is similar to this one, but it is asked in regards to vacuum. We are only using ANALYZE.
https://serverfault.com/questions/212219/postgresql-9-does-vacuuming-a-table-on-the-primary-replicate-on-the-mirror

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Statistics are stored in table, and this table is replicated from primary server to replica. So you don't need and you cannot to run `ANALYZE` on replica (physical replication)

Comment: except live_rows is all 0